# NullPointerException in logcat trace

Tags: java, android, logcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NullpointerException when Launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749787/nullpointerexception-when-launching-activity)

i get this logcat now !!
every time i have this message and force close !!
i asked this question before , but i get a new error ! exu !

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yaAli.package313.hossein110/yaAli.package313.hossein110.know}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:301)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:291)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:330)
    at yaAli.package313.hossein110.know.onCreate(know.java:67)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
    ... 11 more
```

i get new logcat after applaying your answers :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:682)
at yaAli.package313.hossein110.know$1.run(know.java:37)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: yaAli.package313.hossein110.know.onCreate(know.java:67)

Comment: 67 is line that have error ???

Comment: i asked this but i get new error ?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to parse null value into a float.

Comment: old question is :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749787/nullpointerexception-when-launching-activity

Comment: my code is in to link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749787/nullpointerexception-when-launching-activity

Comment: You need to learn how to read a Logcat. In your new LogCat find the line that comes from your code: `at yaAli.package313.hossein110.know$1.run(know.java:37)`. You now know to focus on line 37 in `know.java`. Look back at your LogCat there are multiple line regarding `Integer.parseInt()` and the error involves an empty String... So on line 37 you and trying to turn an empty String into an Integer (you cannot do this). Once you learn how to read your LogCat you won't need to ask for help every time you have a bad line of code.

Answer (score 4):

From your code:

```
String sizefa = sharedpreferences.getString("fontsizefa",null);
...
tvfa.setTextSize(1, Float.valueOf(sizefa).floatValue());
```

When your preferences don't contain "fontsizefa" you are setting it to null. The exception is being thrown because later on you try to cast the null string to a float.

Change it to:

```
String sizefa = sharedpreferences.getString("fontsizefa","0.0");
```

or whatever you want the default size to be.

You are also going to have the same issue with `colorfa` when it is not in your preferences.

Comment: Is it due to `colorfa` being null?

Comment: String colorfa=   sharedpreferences.getString("fontcolorfa","#0276c0");

Comment: Your new exception is being thrown by yaAli.package313.hossein110.know.run(). Looks like you are trying to parse a null string into an Integer.

Comment: i cant find the null string !!!

Comment: whats the run() method ?

Comment: Whatever is on line 37 of know.java

Comment: very very exu : how to see line number ?

Comment: if you say that how can see line number i say you whats it !!

Comment: If you are using Eclipse here is how to show line numbers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640884/eclipse-line-numbers

Comment: line 37 is :         public void run() {s1.scrollTo(0, Integer.valueOf(ln));} });}

Comment: and i set     String ln = null;

Comment: You can't convert a null into an integer, before that line check if ln is null and it it is don't attempt to scroll.

Comment: ln=settings.getString("LASTREADln","");
        if("-1".equals(ln)){ln="0";}
        if(ln!=null){
        final ScrollView s1=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sV1);
        s1.post(new Runnable() {@Override
        public void run() {s1.scrollTo(0, Integer.valueOf(ln));} });}

Comment: String ln = settings.getString("LASTREADln", null); int lnInt = (ln == null)? 0 : Integer.parseInt(ln); then use lnInt instead of ln;